# How to make a modifiable game screen with Python

Tags: python, pygame

I am working on teaching myself python through pygame. I am currently working on creating an RPG template
[Link to my Github](https://github.com/DTNevaeha/Top_Down_RPG_Template)

I am wondering how I can make a customizable level screen if I were to change scenes and each scene has its own set level size (for the intention of level borders). I dont mean the visual screen size (currently 1280x720) but the overall level size.
So when I go to set borders its automatically setup per level without creating an unpassable wall or something each level.

Currently I know I can just do something like this to prevent the top and left side

```py
if self.y < 0:
    self.y = 0
elif self.x < 0:
    self.x = 0
```

I could follow the same pattern for the right / bottom hard coding it exact coordinates. But I was thinking long term what if I had a larger level setting? What if every level was unique in size? Such as just a small room?
What should I do for a suggestion to have it more of something like this below. Where every time I load a new scene, it is auto set and per scene and I don't have to modify the player settings every time.
I linked my github repo above as I figure it would probably be easier to use that then me trying to paste everything.

```py
if self.y < scene.top:
    self.y = scene.top
```

Comment: You can say `if x in range(WIDTH):` and `if y in range(HEIGHT):`.  Even though it looks like it creates a whole list, it doesn't -- that's an efficient operation.

Comment: Plenty of games have invisible entities that do all kinds of things. You could put a `func_levelend` at the end of every map and get it's `x` position when the map loads. Actually, the whole reason it is called `func_levelend` is because it's going to call `func_levelend` when the map loads, and `func_levelend` can set the map end position based on it's `entity` position.

Answer (score 1):

You could store level settings in separate variable and refer to it dynamically:

```
LOCATIONS = {'Dungeon': {'w': 100, 'h': 100},
             'Small Room': {'w': 10, 'h': 5}}

current_location = 'Dungeon'
player = {'x': 0, 'y': 0, 'health': 100}

while player['health']:
    input('Your move: ')
    if player['x'] > LOCATIONS[current_location]['w']:
        player['x'] = LOCATIONS[current_location]['w']
    if player['y'] > LOCATIONS[current_location]['h']:
        player['y'] = LOCATIONS[current_location]['h']
```